# Controller testing with js.erb format

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm using Rails 4.2.5, I've written a controller test for the destroy action, an I'm using ajax call to destroy and using destroy.js.erb file. Please help me to solve the following issue to pass the test when it calls js format, I'm pasting error below.

```
  def destroy  
    @status = @song.destroy  
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.js  
    end  
  end
```

SongsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_song:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat  
      app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:36:in `destroy' 


songs_controller_test.rb    
test "should destroy song" do  
    assert_difference('Song.count', -1) do  
      delete :destroy, id: @song  
    end  

    get :destroy, format:  'js'  
  end
```

destroy.js.erb

```
var element = document.getElementById("<%="song#{@song.id}" %>");    
<%if @status%>  
element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();  
<%end%>
```

Comment: Please format the code in the question accordingly and show the test code too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Rails, how do you functional test a Javascript response format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358214/in-rails-how-do-you-functional-test-a-javascript-response-format)

Comment: Already before asking question ive tried above link, it didnt solve  the error

Comment: Please post the code of your test as well.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll updated code, pls have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `destroy` controller action normally reacts to the `DELETE` HTTP method, so you should use the `format` option when calling `delete`:

```
test "should destroy song" do  
  assert_difference('Song.count', -1) do  
    delete :destroy, id: @song, format: :js
  end  
end
```